# Unmanaged <SecKey> is not convertible to SecKey

Tags: objective-c, encryption, swift, rsa

I want to make RSA encryption in Swift but I came across with a strange error in this line:

```
    var publicKey:SecKeyRef = KeyFormatter.getPublicKeyReference("com.apple.sample.publickey")
```

Normally, in Objective-C it was okay and 'getPublicKeyReference' method returns a SecKeyRef object. But when I type it according to Swift syntax in a Swift file it gives me the error "Unmanaged  is not convertible to SecKey".

KeyFormatter class is still written in Objective-C. So when I call this method (to bridging header) the return type is represented differently in Swift? If so, how can I overcome this problem?

Comment: I guess this is a generic issue with regards to managed/unmanaged code. You may have to marshall/unmarshall the object, or recreate an object using decomposition/composition. Unfortunately I don't know how to do this, otherwise I would have given you the answer; I have to keep it at this hint in hopefully the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-C -> [Working with Cocoa Data Types](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/WorkingWithCocoaDataTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH6-XID_41) -> Scroll all the way down to "Core Foundation".

Because that particular API is not currently audited for memory management semantics, you will need to invoke `takeUnretainedValue()` or `takeRetainedValue()` depending on the memory management semantics of that particular method.

Comment: Thanks that solved my problem. var pKey:SecKeyRef = publicKey.takeRetainedValue()
 with this line now i can get SecKeyRef object without problem. :)